# Why doesn't my shell command using curly/smart quotes work?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

I have written the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
total=0
echo “Please enter 10 numbers >”
read VAR1 VAR2 VAR3 VAR4 VAR5 VAR6 VAR7 VAR8 VAR9 VAR10
total=$((VAR1+VAR2+VAR3+VAR4+VAR5+VAR6+VAR7+VAR8+VAR9+VAR10))
echo $total
```

Running echo in the command line command e.g. (see below) echoes the phrase fine

```
echo "Please enter 10 numbers >”
```

But when I try to run the shell script the text isn't echoed. The script works, if I run it and type in 10 numbers the correct total is returned, but this is not useful if you don't know to type in the numbers!
I have double checked that /bin/bash is correct by running

```
echo $SHELL
```

which returns /bin/bash so I'm not sure what the problem might be.

Comment: How are you running the script?

Comment: You are using the wrong “ you have to use ", small but subtle difference

Comment: @thatotherguy ./filename.txt

Comment: and it should be named filename.sh and not .txt, but this is not the problem

Comment: Do `ls`. See if you have a file called `”` containing your output.

Comment: @DZDomi that is a very sneaky difference. Where's the second one on the keyboard?

Comment: `“` and `”` aren't on any keyboard I know. The location of `"` depends on your keyboard layout.

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ will catch this, by the way. (On a different note -- don't use all-caps names for your own variables; that's a namespace used by variable names with meaning to the operating system or the shell itself).

Comment: It looks like the double quotes you're using are causing the problem. I copied this into my shell and noticed the same issue.

Comment: What's your operating system? MacOS has an option (that any sane person should turn off) to automatically replace regular quotes with curly ones. Microsoft Office apps can do something similar -- part of why programmers are best off using programmer's editors to edit programs.

Comment: @melpomene copy/pasted the different speech marks and this solved the problem. shift apostrophe gives me " but no idea where the others are. will just copy and paste for now

Comment: What editor are you using to write your script? Make sure you turn off "smart quotes" in its editing settings.

Comment: @DZDomi, actually, `.sh` extensions are considered bad form. Scripts shouldn't have any extension at all -- having an extension means they can't be rewritten with a different interpreter without either making the name misleading or needing to change all callers to use the new one. Moreover, using a `.sh` extension for a *bash* script means that users can be mislead into running `sh yourscript.sh`, whereas bash extensions to the POSIX sh specification are only available when run with `bash`, not `sh`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by using "quotes" that don't actually have syntactic meaning to your shell. Consequently, `>”` is redirecting the output of your `echo` command into a file named `”`.

---

#### On MacOS

Go to "System Preferences", then to "Keyboard". Select the "Text" tab, then uncheck "Use smart quotes and dashes".

---

#### With Microsoft applications

Don't use Office apps to edit code, and don't mail code through Outlook or similar. That said, if you *must* type code into an Office app without it being munged, enter AutoCorrect options; select the AutoFormat tab, and uncheck "Straight quotes with smart quotes"

Comment: also have to go to the individual application and go edit > substitutions and uncheck it there too. Thanks for your help

Comment: @pxdr0, which individual application? Worthwhile programmer's editors (gVim, Emacs, Atom, etc) won't have such behavior by default; if you have something that does, it'd be worth calling it out specifically.

Comment: TextEdit. Might be the case on some others too (maybe only apple made ones?)