# New to curl & terminal... getting : zsh: parse error near `}'

Tags: curl, zsh

Help is appreciated!

error: zsh: parse error near `}'

```
curl -i -X POST "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/user/login” -H “Accept: application/json” -H "Content-Type: application/json" —data-binary @- <<EOF {“email”: “mail.xxx.com”, “password”: “XXX”} EOF
```

Comment: remove <<EOF.... EOF . Or replace quote character around "email" .... "XXX"... by `"`. I think it's others character. not normal quote ".

Comment: This is a zsh problem, not a terminal problem. The terminal is just the window you run a shell like bash or zsh inside of; only problems that are specific to how software interacts with _that graphical window itself_ (such as problems changing text's color or whatnot) should be tagged "terminal". I've edited the tagging appropriately.

Comment: Also, whitespace matters. You can't put this all on one line; there **must** be a newline after the `<<EOF`, and another one before the `EOF`.

Comment: @Kai, ...just removing the `<<EOF` and the `EOF` won't result in a working curl command. The OP could replace them with `<<<'` and a final `'`, though. And yes, as you observe, they need to change the "smart quotes" to real ASCII quotes in any event.

Comment: (aside: back in the day, a "terminal" wasn't a program, but a physical piece of hardware that attached to a serial cable and displayed content coming off that line on a screen, and sent content a user typed over that serial cable; a graphical terminal program's purpose is exactly the same thing -- just copying bytes to and from somewhere else where the real work happens, without knowing anything about what those bytes mean, looking at whether they're correct, or doing else except displaying them when they come from the line, or sending them over the line when they come from the keyboard).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ++ used textedit to 1) add lines and 2) fix ASCII quote issue.  Solved thx.

Comment: The one-liner-heredoc side of the question is already asked and answered at [compress heredoc declaration to one line in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49951601/compress-heredoc-declaration-to-one-line-in-bash); the smart-quotes side is asked and answered at [Why doesn't my shell command using curly/smart quotes work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41109888/why-doesnt-my-shell-command-using-curly-smart-quotes-work). I can't close it myself, since I already voted to close with a different reason, and so can't use the dupehammer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yeah my fault about the first sentence, I thought it was unnecessary but I was wrong, thank you for correcting me :)!

Comment: There's no need for a here-anything in this case: `curl ... --data-binary '{"email": ...}'`.

Comment: @DIV : To make the problem even more obvious: If you use a here-document in a command line, the placement of the `<<` is pretty arbitrary, like with the other redirection operators. Hence, for any program `p`, the invocation  `p x y z >out <<EOF a b c` is equivalent to, for example, `>out p x y z a b c <<EOF` or `p x y z a b c <<EOF >out`. Everything you type after the `<<EOF` **on the same line**, simply is considered part of the program arguments, and does not belong to the here doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues: The shell won't acknowledge curly "smart quotes" as syntax; and a heredoc needs to have a newline before its content starts, and after it ends. Compare to:

```
curl -i -X POST "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/user/login" \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  —data-binary @- <<EOF
{"email": "mail.xxx.com", "password": "XXX"}
EOF
```

<sub>Community Wiki since this question probably should be closed as caused by a typo, or could be closed as duplicative of two preexisting questions -- one on the quoting issue, another on one-liner heredocs.</sub>

Comment: Thx for solving initial issue... but email/pw is failing authentication. I know credentials work because I can use an api client w/ same credentials to log in.  I've tried all permutations of answers... can someone pls let this curl newbie know what's wrong with this syntax? ```curl -i -X POST "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/user/login" \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d'{"email”: "email@mail.com", "password”: "psw"}'```

Comment: I dropped the @- <<EOF... because after logging in, I'm able to use the token with the following curl post... so I thought -d '<{"   would be the correct syntax for the email/pw too?  ```curl -i -X POST "http://localhost:8080/api/blog/categories" \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer QSSMyBearerToken--**==" \
-d '{"title": "test create api"}'```

Comment: `--data-binary @-` tells curl to read data from stdin, which means you need to actually _provide data on stdin_, which is what `<<EOF` or `<<<'string'` does. By contrast, when you just pass `--data-binary "content here"`, that's telling curl to read the data straight from the command line and not bother with stdin. They're both perfectly reasonable approaches; occasionally you'll actually need the stdin one, because there's a limit on command-line length, so not all bash variables' contents will always fit on a command line.

Comment: ...as for `'<{...}'`, I don't know where you're getting the `<` from. When you put something in single quotes, that's telling the shell that it's something it shouldn't change, so it's passing the `<` character to curl, and curl is (presumably) passing it to your remote webserver, and then the remote server is presumably (correctly) complaining that `<` isn't a valid way to start a JSON document.

Comment: much appreciate ur help!!...ok... got that...  seems that when I provide email and password parameters via an api client (like postman)... , it should be the same as passing straight from the command line?  its still not clear to me why the credentials are failing via command line but not via an api client passed as parameters behind the same headers.

Comment: just saw ur <{ comment..  my credentials (in my updated comment to ur answer above is...  -d'{"email”: "email@mail.com", "password”: "psw"}'

Comment: isn't this..    data... here it comes... email: my email & password: my password?

Comment: Some of your pasted strings still have `”` characters. Those aren't allowed; they **absolutely must** be `"`.

Comment: I'm using VSCode to type this out cut/paste into terminal (vs originally typing into terminal or cut/pasting from textedit.   I'll retype all the "s and try again.  Much appreciate ... this curl stuff is really throwing me..... fortunately the server logic is working :-)

Comment: Charles Duffy... THANKS for your help!  It was the "s.  I really appreciate it!!!  Here is the final curl command that works... ```curl -i -X POST "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/user/login" \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"email": "mail@Outlook.com", "password": "pw"}'```